# HOW TO LOOP PHP'S PDO BIND PARAM

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bindparam

Im current creating my own query builder now and Im stuck with PDO's prepared statement. Isn't it possible to loop the the PDO's BindParam. I did it using foreach() but it's not working it only on works on the last data that the loop executed.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :a OR fname = :b";

$array = array(":a"=>"10002345", "Josh");
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 

foreach($array as $key => $value ) {
    $stmt->bindParam($key, $value);
}

$stmt->execute();
```

it only binds the last data executed by the loop.

Comment: Also please mention all the key in array as :b is missing

Comment: *"it only on works on the last data that the loop executed"* – Please clarify what that means.

Comment: what I mean is doesn't bind correnctly

Comment: I think you override the params of bind you also have to do __$stmt->execute();__  in the for loop.

Comment: so do I need to put the execute() inside the loop?

Comment: Just give it a try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is better to simply pass your array to `execute`:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :a OR fname = :b";
$array = array("a" => "10002345", "b" => "Josh");
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->execute($array);
```

Or you can do it even simpler with `?` placeholders:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? OR fname = ?";
$array = array("10002345", "Josh"); // you don't even need keys here
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($array);
```

Comment: Why is it "better" to use `?`? You can pass even named parameters to `execute()`.

Answer (score 0):

Only just stumbled across this, but just for future reference...

Firstly, I'll work on the assumption that your example was supposed to read `$array = array(":a"=>"10002345", ":b"=>"Josh");`, as there would be an issue even if your `:b` key was absent.

---

In this bit:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value ) {
    $stmt->bindParam($key, $value);
}
```

You haven't '[passed by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)'. The `$value` should be amended to `&$value`

```
foreach($array as $key => &$value ) {
    $stmt->bindParam($key, $value);
}
```

This is because the `bindParam` method signature requires the value to be a variable reference:

```
public function bindParam ($parameter, &$variable, $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR, $length = null, $driver_options = null) {}
```

(note the `&` before `$variable`).

---

The end result of your original query (sans `&`) is that all `:params` would be set to the value that is in the last iteration of `$value` in your original loop.

So, the result of

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :a OR fname = :b";

$array = array(":a"=>"10002345", ":b"=>"Josh");

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 

foreach($array as $key => $value ) {
    $stmt->bindParam($key, $value);
}

$stmt->execute();
```

Would be `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 'Josh' OR fname = 'Josh'`

---

Using named parameters (`:param`) has advantages over positional params (`?`), so it's worth reserving that option for prepared statements, as opposed to the accepted answer of "it's better to use `?` placeholders", which is not the case.

Comment: Should be the accepter answer, but  beware of the number of named parameters. Using dynamic trough a loop don't work very well with static number of named parameters. I mean that sometimes, array of params/value, could count more or less values than the named parameters in the query..

Answer (score -1):

In my database abstraction layer I use the following utility functions:

```
/**
 * getFieldList return the list with or without PK column
 * @param bool $withID - true when including parameter
 */
static protected function getFieldList( $withID = false )
{
    if( $withID )
        $result = '`' . static::getTableName( ) . '`' .
            '.`' . static::getPrimaryKeyName( ) . '`, ';
    else
        $result = '';

    return $result .= '`' . static::getTableName( ) . '`.' . 
        '`' . implode( '`, `'.static::getTableName( ) . '`.`', static::getFieldNames( ) ) . '`';
}

/**
 * getFieldPlaceholders - 
 * @return string - all PDO place holders prefixed :
 */
static protected function getFieldPlacholders( )
{
    return ':' . implode( ',:', static::getFieldNames( ) );
}

/**
 * getUpdateList - SQL updates section
 * @return string
 */
static private function getUpdateList( )
{
    $result = array( );
    foreach( static::getFieldNames( ) as $field ) {
        if( $field === static::getPrimaryKeyName() ) continue;
        $result[] = '`' . $field . '`=:' . $field;
    }
    return implode( ',', $result );
}

/**
 * Bind the fields to PDO placeholdes
 * @param PDOStatement $stmt statement that the fields are bound to
 * @return void
 */
protected function bindFields( $stmt )
{
    foreach( array_keys($this->fields) as $field ) {
        if( $field === static::getPrimaryKeyName() ) continue;
        $stmt->bindParam( ':' . $field, $this->fields[$field] );

        // echo $field . '->' . $this->fields[$field] . '<br>';
    }
}
/**
 * Bind the fields to the placeholders
 * @param PDOStatement $stmt - that the fields are bind to
 * @return void
 */
protected function bindColumns( $stmt, $withID = false )
{
    if( $withID )
        $stmt->bindColumn( static::getPrimaryKeyName(), $this->ID );
    foreach( static::getFieldNames() as $fieldname )
    {
        $stmt->bindColumn( $fieldname, $this->fields[$fieldname] );
    }   
}

/**
 * parseResultset
 * Set the values of the select results, resets dirty (object is in sync)
 * @param mixed[] $result - associative array
 */
protected function parseResultset( $result )
{
    foreach( $result as $field=> $value ) {
        if( $field === static::getPrimaryKeyName() )
            $this->ID = $value;
        $this->fields[$field] = $value;
    }
    $this->dirty = array();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For anyone still having issues with the above, you can use:

```
$stmt= $conn->prepare($sql);
foreach($data as $key => &$value) {
    $stmt->bindParam(':'.$key.'', $value);   
}  
$stmt->execute();
```